# Trouble using the new shadow caustics in Blender 3.2

Tags: cycles-render-engine, visibility, caustics

So I wanted to make something using the new shadow caustics in Blender 3.2 , like a plane with some random displacement on surface like procedural bubbles or a random height map but doing so the shadow caustics cant be seen . So to see weather I was doing something wrong or not ,  I tried making a 3d glass cup with ridges from a tutorial . After trying many times (like changing position of light or changing light from point to area , increasing brightness) I barely managed to get this done.(image below)
[image]

As you can see the caustics are only visible very close to the plane and after some distance they disappear .

Finally the things that I would like to know are

1. How can I get better caustics without messing with the rotation/position of lights and mesh.
2. How can I make them more visible , like being able to see them at some distance and for finer detail like a displaced plane.

(The mesh has a simple glass shader , subdivision surface and solidify modifier )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that using a sun lamp instead of plain or spot light gives more sharper shadows. Changing the degree of the sun can increase the hardness of shadows making them be more clear and darker .